# Integral of square root of quadric form, over a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, quadratic-forms, trace, spheres, multiple-integral

I'm trying to tackle the following integral:

$$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}{ (\sqrt{\theta^T\Sigma \theta} -  \sqrt{\theta^T \hat \Sigma \theta} )^2 d\theta }$$

Where $\mathbb{S}^{d-1} =\{ \theta \in \mathbb{R}^d: \|\theta\|=1\}$, $\Sigma$ and $\hat \Sigma$ are covariance matrices, so they are symmetric and PSD.

Expanding the square, each of the squared terms can be computed as:

$$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}{ \theta^T\Sigma \theta} \ d\theta  = \frac{| \mathbb{S}^{d-1}|}{d} tr(\Sigma).$$

But I can't make any progress on the product term, i.e.:

$$- 2 \int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}{ \sqrt{\theta^T\Sigma \theta} \sqrt{\theta^T \hat \Sigma \theta}  d\theta }.$$

Any help would be appreciated!